# Is there a standard URL at which to host an RSS feed file?

Tags: http-headers, rss, syndication-feed

I am publishing a website which uses PDF/A exclusively, with no HTML. I’ve been asked to provide an RSS feed, but I have no HTML  tags that I could use to reference it.

Is there a standard URL that clients will check without being told? e.g. /rss.xml

Or is there a standard HTTP header that I could populate with the feed location?